# How to remove performance lags while playing Ragnarok on Wine?

Tags: wine, games, performance, playonlinux

I have just installed Wine and PlayOnLinux.

Its performance is very lagging when I run the game (Ragnarok) and type my username and password.

How can I improve the performance and remove any performance lags?

Answer (score 0):

Turn down graphics and then you can play the game.

Comment: @green7 How is this not an answer? It's giving an explicit solution. Please note that [even answers that are *too* short are still answers and not comments](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments). This is more appropriate as an answer than as a comment.